# Codenameone windows phone 8 build failing due to XMLVM running out of memory

Tags: codenameone

I am seeing this message in the error logs for failed windows phone 8 log.

```
[01/19/16 12:18:58.565]    ERROR: Oh no, XMLVM needs more memory. Try running with -Xmx1G or more.
```

Think you could up the -Xmx setting there for me? If that's not the problem, then there is also this higher up in the log:

```
[01/19/16 12:04:20.276]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory
[01/19/16 12:04:20.276]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory
```

And this lower down (but i think it's a symptom of XMLVM quitting without completing):

```
Main.cs(10,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Object' does not exist in the namespace 'java.lang' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build3939039400849280052xxx\App\App\App.csproj]
Main.cs(10,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Runnable' does not exist in the namespace 'java.lang' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build3939039400849280052xxx\App\App\App.csproj]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking thru the [Codename One discussion group](https://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html) I found this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/gyjS81rpR3w/nSVxzWOJdXEJ

So I guess just adding the build hint `win.doubleRam=true` should solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks David! I looked but somehow missed that.